# Context processor ('AnonymousUser' object is not iterable)

Tags: python, django

In my context processor.py file I filter a table according to a user. This all works fine :

```
def subject_renderer(request):
    return {"Calicount": Tools_Calibrated.objects.filter(
        user=request.user, calibrated=True, issued=True).count(),
    }
```

The problem comes in when I log out and try log back in. Because there is no authenticated user at login I cannot call the query in the context processor.

Question: Why is my context processor function being called when I am not calling the key in the login view template. I know how to solve this with templates but I was wondering how to solve it with context processors. Essentially omit it from one view.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: The context processors are always applied, even if you are not using `Calicount` in you case. Then, handling unwanted cases like Willem Van Onsem is stating in the answer is the way to go.

Comment: Also, having a logic that you don't want to apply everywhere seems to make a better use of tags (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) than context processors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the user is not logged in, so in that case you can not pass `Calicount`.

You thus should implement your context processor with:

```
def subject_renderer(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return {
            'Calicount': Tools_Calibrated.objects.filter(user=request.user, calibrated=True, issued=True).count()
        }
    return {}
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I did thank you. However I would still like to know if there is code i can use to omit the context processor function/functions with coding conditions within the function themselves ?

Comment: @Andre: but here we do check if the user is authenticated in the context processor. As the documentation says: *Each processor is applied in order.*, so you can not "disable" a context processor for some views, you need to write the logic that simply will return an empty dictionary, such that nothing is added to the context.

Comment: Okay thank you, I guess I naively thought you were able to target the functions similarly to that of template tags. Perhaps on an __init__ method within the function. I never read the documentation properly. Thank you for the reply and sorry for the naive question!